# Is it possible to deobfuscate weird lua bytecode with strings and symboles in it?

Tags: lua, reverse-engineering

I have this decompiled lua code which is obfuscated, but what is strange is that the bytecode has letters and symbols in it, here is a sample of it:

```lua
local L0_1, L1_1, L2_1, L3_1, L4_1, L5_1
L0_1 = _G
L1_1 = {}
L2_1 = {}
L2_1["%7\188\003\019s\237\136\155\221\162\015}*QV"] = "\253\020N\161\192\021\238[<\138\020\248\244\171=\138\148\142\230\a\015_D\219CGq\vP\028?&"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If more code is required, here is a pastebin paste: https://pastebin.com/UZzKvj9L

Comment: These encrypted strings will be decrypted later in the code.

Comment: The sample isn't complete.

Comment: If more code is required, here is a pastebin paste: https://pastebin.com/UZzKvj9L

Comment: Decryptor is in the code that reads this file.